# WPF threading: can I update a control's data context in a non-UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Can we update the data context of a WPF control in a non-UI thread?

Say we have a `Label` that has `MyClass` as data context, and bind `Content` to `MyProperty`:

`<Label Name="label" Content="{Binding MyProperty}" />`,

where `MyClass` is simply:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int _myField;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myField;
        }
        set
        {
            _myField = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In a non-UI thread, we can do `myClass.MyProperty = "updated"` to update the content of the label, but we cannot do `label.Content = "updated"` directly. Is that correct?

**My own answer**:

Here's what I've found:

- From a non-UI thread, you **cannot** update a control;
- From a non-UI thread, you **can** update properties of a control's data context;
- From a non-UI thread, you **cannot** add items to or remove items from an `ObserverableCollection` that is bound to a control. But there is a **workaround**: http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, that is correct. There are additional caveats with collections as well (The `CollectionChanged` event has to be executed in the UI thread).

Usually, you are using `ObservableCollection<T>` for binding to a collection. If you update this collection from a non-UI thread, the code will break, as events are fired from the same thread they are executed on (`ObservableCollection<T>` fires an event when changes in the collection happen). To circumvent this, you have to supply a delegate to a custom implementation of `ObservableCollection<T>` which fires the event in the UI thread (using the Dispatcher).

Comment: Could you please give me more details on collections? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got a solution here: http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx

Comment: I used that one as well, but there are cases where the code doesn't work (some wpf objects don't inherit from DispatcherObject).

Comment: So could you please share any better solution?

Comment: well, mine is not ideal either - `Dispatcher` has `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` as members, you could supply those to your ViewModel and subsequently to your collection.