# Examples of collection changed events on Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have listbox in a WPF application that displays an observable collection of photo objects.  When a photo is added to the collection the UI needs show the new image right away. I understand this can be handled using the CollectionChanged event.  I have looked around for examples on how to use the handle collection changed events but I havent found anything that worked. Does anyone know of any good examples?

Another thing is that the images are coming from a directory on my computer and i have a file system watcher watching the directory for new photos being added or deleted. I am currently using file system event handler to update the collections when a photo is added or deleted but the problem is when i add a new photo  to the directory, an exception is thrown saying that I cant modify the collection from a thread thats not the main thread.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem too?  Here is the code for this problem:

```
public class PhotoList : ObservableCollection<Photo>
{
    DirectoryInfo _directory;
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public PhotoList()
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        MessageBox.Show("Watching..");
        _watcher.Filter = "*.jpg";
        _watcher.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        _watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemWatcher_Created);

        _directory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach(FileInfo f in _directory.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
        {
            Add(new Photo(f.FullName));
        }
    }


    public string Path
    {
        set
        {
            _directory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures));
            Update();
        }
        get
        {
            return _directory.FullName;
        }
    }

    public void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Add(new Photo(e.FullPath));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: `ObservableCollection<T>` already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, so simply bind on that object and you are fine, the UI will get the updates happening in the collection automatically.

Second question: See this post: [WPF threading: can I update a control's data context in a non-UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418767/wpf-thread-can-i-update-a-controls-data-context-in-a-non-ui-thread/4418781#4418781) and the accompening comments.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the Add(new Photo(e.FullPath)) inside of Dispatcher.Invoke().  That way Add will be called on the UI thread